# How to Converting Date String with timezone to timestamp milliseconds in Python 2.7

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have this date string in python `"2016-12-12T00:00:00+01:00"`

How do I convert the said date string with timestamp to timestamp in milliseconds so I can compute use the value so I can compute it?

Purpose: 
to_timestamp_milliseconds("2017-12-12T00:00:00+01:00") + (10500 * 1000)

Answer (score 0):

Easy

`dt = dateutil.parser.parse("2017-12-12T00:00:00+01:00")

timestamp = int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))`

now you got seconds, I guess you can convert it to milliseconds your self